# E2E test for Angular File Saver

Tags: angularjs, protractor, filesaver.js

I am planning to use [Angular File Saver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) for saving file from string in AngularJS (1.7) app.

However, I want to be able to write E2E tests using protractor and I'm not clear how I could achieve it.

I see that [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js) in turn creates an anchor tag with a particular namespace. My hunch is that I could rely on finding anchor tag with that namespace, then get its `href` attribute and finally check the URL.